# When to use « voilà quel » instead of « voilà qui » or « voilà ce qui »

Tags: expressions, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-interrogatifs

> Je devais m’occuper de toute la paperasse. **Voilà quel** était mon travail.

I’m not sure when to use « voilà quel » instead of the other two expressions. Incidentally, does the « quel » here refer to « (de) m’occuper de toute la paperasse »?

> Je devais m’occuper de toute la paperasse. **Voilà qui** était mon travail.
>
> Je devais m’occuper de toute la paperasse. **Voilà ce qui** était mon travail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"**Quel**"* is a pronoun, subject of *"était"*, and it agrees with *"**mon travail**"* which refer to *"(de) m’occuper de toute la paperasse."*

*"Voilà qui + [être] + 'adjective'"* can be used with *qui* referring to any possible subject (e.g. *voilà qui était fatigant*) but *"voilà qui + [être] + 'nominal group'"* is rarely<sup>1</sup> used when 'nominal group' refers to anything not a living being so instead of *"voilà qui était mon travail."*, I'd rather write:

> Je devais m’occuper de toute la paperasse. Voilà **ce qu'était** mon travail.

While I'm somewhat reluctant to support your last sentence, I'm not against *"voilà ce qui était l'objet de son attention"* so there should be no reason to reject *"voila ce qui était mon travail"*. Like with *voilà qui*, I still prefer when *"ce qui était"* is followed by an adjective (e.g. *voilà ce qui était difficile*.)

*Voilà* is a *[présentatif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/pr%C3%A9sentatif)*. Etymologically, it is the imperative verbal expression ***vois là*** (word by word: **see there**). *Voilà* can be followed by pronouns commonly used in questions like:

> *Voilà **comme[nt]** il faut faire.*
>
> *Voilà **qui** tu attends.*
>
> *Voilà **où** nous en sommes.*
>
> *Voilà **pourquoi** votre fille est muette.*

The object is often something visible (literally or figuratively) that was already presented, while *voici* (see here) is more for something that is being presented.

***Quel*** agrees in gender and number with its object, so:

> *Voilà **quelle** est **ma tâche***.
>
> *Voilà **quels** sont **mes ancêtres***.
>
> *Voilà **quelles** sont **mes œuvres***.

When followed by a nominal group:

> - ***Voilà quel*** + être is presenting the quality of something or someone that has been previously shown or described.
>
> *Un élève studieux, voilà quel est mon fils* → This is "what" is my son (quality).
>
> *Un taudis, voila quelle est sa maison !*
>
> - ***Voilà qui*** + être is telling the identity or the quality of someone, or is presenting something not yet described, or is qualifying someone or something.
>
> *Voilà qui est mon fils* → This is "who" is my son (identity).
>
> *Voilà qui est sa maison ! N'est-elle pas jolie !*
>
> *Qui sommes nous ? Voilà qui est une question intéressante !*
>
> - ***Voilà ce qui*** + être is detailing something presented and cannot be used with people.
>
> *Ce grand chateau, voilà ce qui est sa maison !*

When followed by an adjective:

> ***Voilà quel*** + être is not used.
>
> ***Voilà qui*** + être can be used to qualify anything/anyone, the stress is on the adjective.
>
> *voilà qui est cher !* → How expensive is this !
>
> *voilà qui est déplacé !* → How inappropriate is this !
>
> ***Voilà ce qui*** + être can be used to qualify anything, the stress is on the object.
>
> *Voilà ce qui est cher* → Here is what is expensive.

<sup>1</sup><sub>but not impossible, I have found these examples: *voilà qui était une perspective intéressante*, *voilà qui était un discours nouveau chez cet analyste financier*, *voilà qui était bien une ultime blague de notre grand-père*.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure you can't use "*qui*" here. *Voilà qui est intéressant*.

Comment: “Voilà qui était mon travail” is possible, *qui* is also the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Quel is an interrogative adjective.

> Je devais m’occuper de toute la paperasse. Voilà quel était mon travail.

It's like you answer the question: *Quel était ton travail?* Quel is used here as the predicative (attribut in French) of the verb **est** car mon travail c'est le sujet.

> Je devais m’occuper de toute la paperasse. Voilà ce qui était mon
>   travail.

It's like you answer the question: *Qu'est-ce qui était ton travail?* However, we don't use **qu'est-ce qui** to find the predicative of the verb but the subject of it.

> Je devais m’occuper de toute la paperasse. Voilà qui était mon
>   travail.

**Qui** is used here as a subject relative pronoun.

Comment: *Qui* is a subject relative pronoun that can be used for both people and things. *Voilà qui était ...* is perfectly correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Laure.I meant only as an interrogative pronoun.I will edit my answer.